# kafka rest proxy performance impact on other producers

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-rest-proxy

What is the impact on performance while using kafka rest proxy.

Does it effect other kafka producers/clients' performance in any which way?

What is the downside / disadvantages of using kafka rest proxy.

Answer (score 0):

Adding new Kafka clients in any format don't impact each other in terms of performance until you start reaching disk/memory/network limits of the brokers

Downside of using the proxy is that you should prefer native Kafka TCP connection rather than HTTP, if performance is your deciding factor .You can always write your own HTTP server that does a very small subset of accepting messages to forward to Kafka and consuming messages to act on them, without exposing the internals of the Kafka topics themselves